# What's the best way to generate charts/graphs/data visualizations in Adobe Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, charts, data-visualization

I'm new to Flex but need to generate some visualizations of some time-based data. Any recommendations for tools that would work well in Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to pay for it (I think it's in the USD $250 range), Flex Builder Pro is definitely the way to go. The graphing and charting power in the libraries is impressive. It's quite simple to generate nice looking, complex graphs with not much coding.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to keep an eye on a new project called [Axiis](http://www.twgonzalez.com/blog/?p=172) that was recently announced by Tom Gonzalez, a prominent Flex developer. It's a data visualization framework that should make custom charting very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Flex Builder Pro gives you access to the graph visualization library in mx.charts.

If you want an open source solution, you can try [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Something other that the builtin mx.charts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the standard Flex Charting - which is extremely configurable - we've been able to make it look pretty much how we want it to...

However, also take a look at iLog Elixir - they provide some superb additional charts that you might find useful - particularly the 3D charts. The Radar chart can be very effective in some situations but you really need the RIGHT place to use such a thing. Also they have a good heatmap and pivot charts.

Regards,

Jamie.

Answer (score 0):

Some very interesting charts, and they have free-with-logo and pay-and-have-the-source versions, is amCharts. They can be used directly in a web page, feeding settings by XML and data by CSV (as services, by javascript or whatever) and also inside Flex projects.